# Netbeans C++ debugger not showing variables

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans, gdb, cygwin

I've debugged using Netbeans with Java before, but I'm stuck trying to debug a C++ project. I go to debug > debug project, and it appears to sort of work but there are never any variables shown. Also sometimes a new tab titled "Dissasembly" pops up and I don't know why.

I'm using Netbeans 8 with Cygwin on Windows 8 (and yes I have gcc/gdb installed and the PATH set up correctly).

[image: example of it not working]

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, might be that your gdb can't "understand" the format of the debugging symbols generated by your gcc.

Check the versions of each and consider updating, or try -ggdb option for gcc.

> -ggdb
>   Produce debugging information for use by GDB. This means to use the most expressive format available (DWARF 2, stabs, or the native format if neither of those are supported), including GDB extensions if at all possible.